# NPM Install results in 402 payment required for random packages

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, npm-install

npm install causes a E402 error on many packages.

The problem will come eveyrtime I try it, but the package that caused the failure message tends to change. When checking the log however many of the packages seem to hit a 402 error.

I've tried swapping node versions, trying 8, 10 and 11. All return the same issue

Log file gives output like the following

```
216 http fetch GET 402 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/SITE/_packaging/dev/npm/registry/prismjs 90ms
217 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for react@^16.4.1 402 Payment Required: react@^16.4.1
218 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for prismjs@^1.15.0 402 Payment Required: prismjs@^1.15.0
219 http fetch GET 402 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/SITE/_packaging/dev/npm/registry/react-disqus-comments 89ms
220 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for react-disqus-comments@^1.1.1 402 Payment Required: react-disqus-comments@^1.1.1
221 http fetch GET 402 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/SITE/_packaging/dev/npm/registry/react-helmet 90ms
222 http fetch GET 402 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/SITE/_packaging/dev/npm/registry/react-dropdown 90ms
223 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for react-helmet@^5.2.0 402 Payment Required: react-helmet@^5.2.0
224 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for react-dropdown@^1.6.2 402 Payment Required: react-dropdown@^1.6.2
225 http fetch GET 402 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/SITE/_packaging/dev/npm/registry/react-icons 76ms
226 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for react-icons@^3.2.0 402 Payment Required: react-icons@^3.2.0
227 http fetch GET 402 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/SITE/_packaging/dev/npm/registry/react-twitter-widgets 77ms
228 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for react-twitter-widgets@^1.7.1 402 Payment Required: react-twitter-widgets@^1.7.1
229 http fetch GET 402 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/SITE/_packaging/dev/npm/registry/react-share 83ms
230 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for react-share@^2.0.0 402 Payment Required: react-share@^2.0.0
231 http fetch GET 402 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/SITE/_packaging/dev/npm/registry/swagger-ui 77ms
232 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for swagger-ui@^3.20.1 402 Payment Required: swagger-ui@^3.20.1
233 http fetch GET 402 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/SITE/_packaging/dev/npm/registry/tachyons-sass 82ms
234 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for tachyons-sass@^4.9.3 402 Payment Required: tachyons-sass@^4.9.3
235 http fetch GET 402 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/SITE/_packaging/dev/npm/registry/url-join 83ms
236 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for url-join@^4.0.0 402 Payment Required: url-join@^4.0.0
237 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
238 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 1442ms
239 silly saveTree iofog.org@1.1.0
240 verbose stack Error: 402 Payment Required: ajv@^5.5.2
240 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (/Users/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/fetch.js:42:19)
240 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/Users/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
240 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
240 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
240 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
240 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
240 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (/Users/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
240 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/Users/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
240 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
240 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
240 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
240 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
241 verbose cwd /Users/USER/iofog.org
242 verbose Darwin 17.7.0
243 verbose argv "/Users/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/bin/node" "/Users/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/bin/npm" "i"
244 verbose node v8.16.0
245 verbose npm  v6.4.1
246 error code E402
247 error 402 Payment Required: ajv@^5.5.2
248 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I expect to install and then get to run the website code, which I was doing before, but after a git reset on it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this is telling you is that the server that you're fetching from has some kind of limitation for which they expect you to pay to relieve.

Based on the stack trace, it looks like you're fetching from `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/edgeworx/_packaging/dev/npm/registry/`.  It could be that you need to authorize the connection before you can access the registry with Azure.  Or, you could just configure your NPM to use the public repos.

```
 npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.com/
```

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to fix it :)